# React - logic applied in ComponentDidMount gets undone

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that simply renders html (using dangerouslySetHtml in this instance) and after rendering the content, I add an eventlisteners to some elements with a specific class to have a 'click-to-copy' function. I do this in the componentDidMount but I cannot see the expected results at this stage. I apply the same logic in the componentDidUpdate and it works like a charm.

Any idea as to why this might be happening?

```
==== Component ====
  componentDidMount() {
    clipboard(".test");
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    clipboard(".test");
  }

  render() {
    var props = this.props,
        config = props.config;

        return (
          <section className="componentName" datacomponent="componentName"}>
            <div className="text-1 emphasis-font-web-safe">
              <DangerouslySetInnerHtml text={config.get('text1')} />
            </div>
          </section>
        );
      }
    }
```

UpdatCopmponentView is a simple function which adds event listener :

```
function clipboard(selector) {
    var elementsToBeCopied = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    _.forEach(elementsToBeCopied, function (elementToBeCopied) {
      elementToBeCopied.className += ' tooltip';

        elementToBeCopied.addEventListener('click',function(){
            copyText(this);
        } ,false);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you include your code? An explanation of it isn't as useful to us as an actual copy of what you were up to, especially if it happens to be something small.

Comment: is the parameter `elementsToBeCopied` `undefined` in `clipboard()` when called from `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: what does DangerouslySetInnerHtml ?

Comment: @DamienLeroux The element isnt undefined when called in clipboard. dangerouslySetHtml helps inject html string  and render it ad normal html elements.

Comment: ok. By 'what does', i mean: 'could you share the code?'

Comment: putting a break point in `render()` or the `render()` of `DangerouslySetInnerHtml `, does it fire twice?

Answer (score 0):

Putting a break point in `render()` or the `render()` of `DangerouslySetInnerHtml`, does it fire twice? When `render()` is called after `componentDidMount`, attached DOM events are removed and `componentDidMount` is not called anymore. That could explain your problem and why it works with `componentDidUpdate`